# Function with try/except don't return ! In python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, function, try-except

I've tried to write a function which tries if the GCD of the variable 'a' and 26 is 1, and if not then return the variable pgcd as True in order to quit a 'While'. But the function doesn't change the value of pgcd which stays False so it stays into the 'While'. I don't understand why the value isn't change. Could you help me :)

```
def couplepgcd(pgcd):
    try:
        assert gcd(a,26) == 1 
        pgcd = True
    except Exception:
        print("a et 26 doivent être premiers entre eux !")
    return pgcd
```

...

```
pgcd = False
while pgcd == False:
    [...]
    couplepgcd(pgcd)
```

Comment: You probably should just use an if, instead of a try/except.  assert should raise AssertionError - usually catching all exceptions is a poor idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pgcd` variable inside of your `couplepgcd` function is local to that function, so when you call it even if `pgcd` is changed to `True` and returned from the function, this does not change the value of the `pgcd` variable that you are using in the loop condition.

You are also unnecessarily passing in the current value of `pgcd` into the function, this isn't used anywhere so it isn't necessary.

Here are all of the options you can use to fix this:

- Assign the return value of the function to the variable `pgcd`:

  ```
  pgcd = False
  while pgcd == False:
      [...]
      pgcd = couplepgcd()
  ```
- Use the `global` statement within the function so that assignment to `pgcd` within your function overwrites the global variable (this only works if you `while` loop is in the global scope, or on Python 3.x you could use the `nonlocal` keyword):

  ```
  def couplepgcd():
      global pgcd
      try:
          assert gcd(a,26) == 1 
      except Exception:
          print("a et 26 doivent être premiers entre eux !")
  ```
- Use a mutable variable that you modify within the function, for example with a one-element list:

  ```
  def couplepgcd(pgcd):
      try:
          assert gcd(a,26) == 1 
          pgcd[0] = True
      except Exception:
          print("a et 26 doivent être premiers entre eux !")

  pgcd = [False]
  while not pgcd[0]:
      [...]
      couplepgcd(pgcd)
  ```

Comment: also you should avoid `global` for style and maintainability. TCL has a nice compromise keyword called `upvar` that looks upward in the call-stack: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/upvar.htm

Comment: In Python 3, that's called `nonlocal`.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because you don't save the result of the `couplepgcd` function.

```
pgcd = False
while pgcd == False:
    [...]
    pgcd = couplepgcd(pgcd)
```

Comment: yeah, the behavior you were expecting is called pass-by-reference in many languages. you could emulate it with something akin to Java's "boxing": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference

Comment: Of course, If I forget such a thing, what is the world coming to ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: You're welcome. But make sure you also check other answers, especially the ones saying that it's kind of wrong to use assert + try..catch to do the check. I also see a use case for standard IF statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your `couplepgcd` function tries to return `pgcd` even if it hasn't assigned it. If there's an exception, `pgcd` is never set, and returning it is an error.

In any case your `pgcd` function seems to be an awfully long-winded way to say:

```
def couplepgcd(a):
   return gcd(a, 26) == 1
```

Also, remember that `assert` statements will be stripped out when your program is run in optimized mode (`python -O`) which will *break* the original function. You shouldn't use `assert` the way you're using it.

You should then be passing in `a` rather than `pgcd` (there's no reason to pass that in, since you don't use it and can't change it) and assigning the *return value* of `couplepgcd()` to `pgcd` in your loop. Or, since it's so short, don't bother writing the function in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question (see the other answers for that), but the method you are using (assert and catching the exception) is not typical for logic control.  It is much more common to use an if statement:

```
def couplepgcd(pgcd):
    if gcd(a,26) == 1:
        pgcd = True
    else:
        print("a et 26 doivent être premiers entre eux !")
    return pgcd
```